git branch and merging from different branches
In my project I have a branch I used to work on called v.12 which has since deployed to prod. I created a feature branch based on v.12 after prod deployment, called v.12-fixes and had been working on it.
Since then, my colleague has created a new branch called v.13 based on v.12, but without v.12-fixes.
If I want to use v.13 and include the changes from v.12-fixes, what is the best way to do it?

Do you want to modify v.13 branch i.e. push the changes from v.12-fixes to v.13, or pull in changes from v.13 into v.12-fixes

All strongly depends on what "I want to use v.13" means. In my opinion, a branch that is named "v.12-fixes" should only contain the fixes needed for "v.12", not other random stuff.

In this situation, the best approach is to rebase your local branch v.12-fixes on top of v.13. This operation will rewrite every commit you have on the branch v.12-fixes, moving its base to the tip of v.13, and including all the changes from v.13 into v.12-fixes.
To rebase your branch, first fetch the branch v.13 from the remote repository (I'm assuming its name is origin).
git fetch origin v.13

Then, rebase your local branch v.12-fixes on top of the tracking branch origin/v.13.
# make sure to be on the branch to rebase
git checkout v.12-fixes

# rebase v.12-fixes on top of v.13
git rebase v.13

Warning: Before proceeding, if the local branch v.12-fixes has already been pushed to the remote, make sure that nobody else has based their work on it yet. As said before, rebasing re-writes the history, therefore if other developers have based their work on your current version of v.12-fixes, their changes would be based on a history that doesn't exist anymore after the rebase. If this is your case, coordinate first the rebase with the other developers to safeguard their work.

Thanks for the response..will try it when github if back online again...(I am pretty sure if will work)

It works..thanks dani
